# Alamofire arraylist

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
 self.manager!.request(url+"Find/"+(self.userLogged?.teacherId)!, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,headers: headers
                ).responseObject(keyPath: "") { (response: DataResponse<[Teacher]>) in
```

I need the response to be arraylist of teacher. not teacher object. how can i specify that ? thank you using swift 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the responseObject you can get the JSON object by using

```
self.manager!.request(url+"Find/"+(self.userLogged?.teacherId)!, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,headers: headers).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Teacher]>) in
    let teacherArray = response.result.value
    // You can access your array here.
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: cant i attach DataResponse<teacher[]> lke that? do i really need to loop and do mapping by mself?

Comment: You can use a third party library like [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper). This is up to you.

Comment: I am using it, however i specify it like this DataResponse<Teacher> it works, but it returns one teacher.I need <[teacher]> arraylist.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it please.

Comment: thank you , thats exactly what i wanted to keep my code clean